# Remove for loop: Extracting Neighbour Distances from Matrix containing distances between all instances

Tags: matlab, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to create a matrix of distances between my N data points and their K neighbours. The data matrix is `NxA` so the distance matrix `Y_distances` is `NxN` and each`i,jth` entry is the distance between data point `i` and `j`. Using `knnsearch` I have a matrix of the row numbers of each data point and its `K` neighbours called `IDX`, I then perform dimensionality reduction and want to use the distances between the neighbouring points in the lower dimension space. I am currently using a for loop as such:

```
 no_neighbours=k;
 IDX = knnsearch(X,X,'K',no_neighbours);
 Y_Distances = sqrt(dist2(y, y));

for i = 1:N
    for j= 1:A
        Y_neighbour_distances = Y_Distances(i,IDX(i,j));
    end
end
```

Any suggestions on how to avoid these loops as they are quite time consuming on large datasets.

Comment: Show us the code involving `knnsearch` too  and how that plugs into the listed code?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need this call to sparse:

```
I = ndgrid(1:N, 1:K);
sparse(I, IDX, Y_Distances)
```